# Extend MapActivity and another class: avoid multiple inheritance

Tags: android

I would have a class hierarchy like in photo.

Usually in this case it's usefull pattern Decorator in Java, but with MapActivity is not possible, how can i do?

[Valid XHTML http://dl.dropbox.com/u/278026/View.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/278026/View.png)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot "do". As you say, it is impossible in Java.

You can switch to composition instead of inheritance, and move the logic from `AbstractMyActivity` into something that a `MapActivity` can also hold onto.

Comment: Composition is the way to go here, thumbs up!

Comment: Yes, but i cannot create a Composite class AbstractMapActivity where the component is MapActivity, because i cannot use MapView inside a class AbstractMapActivity that doesn't extends MapActivity

Comment: @Mark: I recommend that you start by learning what object oriented programming is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming  Then, I recommend that you learn what composition is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_Pattern Now, I will admit that composition is not ideal here. I wish Java had mixins like Ruby does. But you are clearly confusing composition with abstraction, which are not related.